# Does anyone know the purpose of the malware,ios,social_engineering file on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a jailbroken iPhone, and I noticed that it contains a file called `social_engineering,ios,url_expression` at the path:

`/private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/Google/social_engineering,ios,url_expression`

The file is roughly 11MB in size.

Does anyone know what the purpose of this file is?

Thank you,
James Pedersen

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Apple products but it's probably this:

"This database, provided by Google, is used by mobile Safari to check for known malicious web sites. To check if this is activated on your iOS device, go to Settings > Safari, then look for the Fraud Warning slider."

Ref: https://web.archive.org/web/20111017184637/http://blog.intego.com/2011/10/14/google-safe-browsing-data-syncs-to-ios-devices-via-itunes/